# Error while display json from sql database - PHP

Tags: php, sql, json

I made a script to display data from online SQL database into JSON format.
The problem is, I don't have the format i was looking for, I get 2 [ more while i wanted only one:

A part of my script:

```
$sql = "select pseudo, dixsec from user;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$rows[] = $r;


}
$arrray = array("server_response" => array($rows));
print json_encode($arrray);
```

What i get (You can see here that i have 2 "["):
[Json i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqVh1.png)

How can i solve it and get only one "[" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$rows is already an array.

Try with: `$arrray = array("server_response" => $rows);`